# Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate JavaScript Templates Missing

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate Edition, when creating a "New Project" in "Templates" I cannot see any JavaScript Templates. I am in VS modality for JavaScript Development.

Any idea how to show JS default template in VS 2013 Ultimate (similarly at what you see on VS 2013 Express edition)?

Comment: I see this project as add in to VS, but Ia mconcerning to have a solutions directly from MS if possible http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msdn_answers/archive/2013/04/10/how-can-i-create-pure-client-side-web-apps-using-html5-css3-and-javascript-using-visual-studio.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue. You will need to go to the File tab, select new, and then select file. After select a new file you will have the option to choose a .js file but not a project. select a new .js file. After selected a new .js file, go over to the right in the solution explorer and start a new project from there and just continue to add new file into that project.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem but was able to get it to show up:

[image: Visual Studio javascript template]

Because I was using Node.js I first made sure I had the latest node version.
But this is what gave me the templates you see above...

Azure Tools for VS 2013: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=323510

I guess it makes sense... don't know... it just worked!

I also found the Blank NODE.JS (version 4) template to create a project, and use NPM automatically to get all dependencies. The App.js file looks like this:

[image: The app.js file auto-created]

And the solution folder:

[image]